# javascript mouseenter not firing when html onmouseenter does

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

When using the above code, "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" are fired once at start.
"onmouseenter" and "onmouseleave" are fired when expected. How do I make "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" fire when expected ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="banner" style="border: 2px solid black; height: 200px"></div>
        <div style="border: 2px solid black; height: 200px"></div>
        <script>
            var banner = document.getElementById("banner");

            banner.setAttribute("onmouseenter", 'console.log("onmouseenter")');
            banner.setAttribute("onmouseleave", 'console.log("onmouseenter")');
            banner.addEventListener("mouseenter", console.log("mouseenter"));
            banner.addEventListener("mouseleave", console.log("mouseleave"));

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The event listener accepts a function *that it will fire* when the event happens. At the moment you're calling `console.log` immediately, rather than waiting for the event to fire. If you place the console logs inside a function this won't happen.

```
banner.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  console.log("mouseenter");
});

banner.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  console.log("mouseleave");
});
```

On a side note that's the second time this week I've seen `setAttribute` used with `onclick`. I would advise against using that method and stick with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works. I'll try to understand why it makes a difference.

Comment: I've improved the explanation a little.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" fire when expected ?

`addEventListener` is **expecting a function** as a callback handler **rather than result of a function call** (i.e. `console.log`) You need to wrap them in a `function`

```
  banner.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){ console.log("mouseenter") });
  banner.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){ console.log("mouseleave") });
```